# missing libmpfr.so.6 when using a cross-compiler

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cross-compiling, ubuntu-18.04, buildroot

I am using Ubuntu 18.04

I built a **mips** cross-compiler using **buildroot**, but when I tried to test whether it would work,I got this message

```
/home/daisy/repos/repo/buildroot/output/host/bin/../libexec/gcc/mipsel-buildroot-linux-uclibc/9.3.0/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libmpfr.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I searched for solutions , one of which said this:

```
sudo pacman -S mpfr
```

Well , my Linux isn't archlinux, this didn't work for me.
somebody please tells me how to deal with it.

Comment: You might install (with `apt` or `aptitude`) some package such as `gcc-9-mipsel-linux-gnu` and your question should show the *exact* `configure` command used to build your cross-compiler. You may need to edit `/etc/ld.so.conf` then run `ldconfig`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch After I downloaded _buildroot_ package , I used ```make clean ``` and ```make menuconfig ``` ,then entered a BIOS-like GUI where I configured all by making choices .After that ,I used ```make```  , then the cross compiler was built . Thus , I truly don't know how to show the _exact_ `configure` command . Could you explain more detailed ?

Comment: Please *edit your question* don't comment it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch what I said is that I don't know what I should add , and hope you can tell me more specifically. You say I need to to show the configure command ,and I respond that I configured it within graphical interface , thus I cannot give exact configure command ,or I'm wrong with it and hope you can point it out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu, **apt** command `(Advanced Packaging Tool)` is used for  performing such functions as *installation* of new software packages, *upgrade* of existing software packages, updating of the package list index, and even *upgrading* the entire Ubuntu system.

Try this command :-

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install libmpfr6
```

This will install shared libraries: **libmpfr.so.6** to your Ubuntu system.

Hope It Helps !

Comment: it shows ```Unable to locate package libmpfr6``` , how to solve this ?

Comment: @syzwlop try command `sudo apt-get update`and then `sudo apt install libmpfr6`

Comment: I tried all your commands , but it still got the same result as above . Is it the problem of apt source list ? I had changed my ```/etc/apt/sources.list``` before

Answer (score 5):

The above suggestions of installing libmpfr on your host system are wrong. Buildroot is supposed to have build libmpfr, it should be present in host/lib, and picked up by the cross-compiler by virtue of it having a proper RPATH. If it doesn't work, we need to figure out why, but the correct thing is not to install libmpfr on your host system.